# Google Function - How to handle multiple resource path In Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a small rest server using `google functions`. Would someone please let me know how to handle multiple resource path?

Currently I am doing following way.

```
def func_handler(request):
    print(request.path)
    if request.path == "/":
        return handle_root_path(request)

    if request.path == "/test":
        return handle_test_path(request)
```

As google function is using `flask` underneath for python, is there any way I can handle it using `@app.route` decorator?

Comment: Did the answer below solve your question? If so, please consider upvoting it so that the community would find the answer helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [wrote an article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/use-multiple-paths-in-cloud-functions-python-and-flask-fc6780e560d3) on that. Have a look and take inspiration of it!

Keep in mind that is not a good idea. Prefer Cloud Run instead.

Comment: yes, I stumbled upon that article.